# ASP.NET VB Dropdown List

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameters

ASP.NET dropdown populates correct items, but VB will not receive selected item. Not sure where to go from here. Could you please tell me why this is not occurring and how to resolve. I need to pass the selected item as a variable to the vb script.

**ASP.NET:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFacultyAssign" runat="server"  
     DataSourceID="FacultyAssign" Visible="false"
     DataTextField="FULLNAME" DataValueField="FULLNAME"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FacultyAssign" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:nameOfString %>" 
     SelectCommand="EXEC SOCC.dbo.sp_util_FacultyAssign @PEOPLE_CODE_ID">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PEOPLE_CODE_ID" QueryStringField="USER" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**VB**

```
    Partial Public Class NotesContact
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


        Me.TextBox1.Text = Context.User.Identity.Name
        Me.Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today

        If (Not IsPostBack) Then
            ViewState("RefUrl") = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SAVE_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SAVE.Click

        Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection
        Dim MyCommand As SqlCommand

        'Create a connection to the SQL Server.
        MyConnection = New SqlConnection("server=**************************")

        MyCommand = New SqlCommand("myStoredProcedure", MyConnection)

        'Set the command type as StoredProcedure.
        MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
MyCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FACASSIGN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200))
MyCommand.Parameters("@FACASSIGN").Value = Me.ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedItem.Text

        'Open and execute the statement
        MyCommand.Connection.Open()
        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MyConnection.Close() 'Close the connection
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Why is the drop down not visible?  If it is not visible, are you sure it is being rendered on the page?

Comment: Put `autopostback=true` to dropdown

Comment: it was not visible because it was being done on a production server.

Comment: Kevin I set the dropdown to visible, I can see the dropdown. When I selected a name in the dropdown it does not send to vb. I set the autopostback = true as nelek suggested but no luck.

Comment: I'm assuming you are referring to this line of code: MyCommand.Parameters("@FACASSIGN").Value = Me.ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedItem.Text. What value _does_ it have?  You could also try using ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedValue instead

Comment: The value/Text that was selected is the Name Rebecca, it still is not capturing the name rebecca. I tried selected value as well with no results. There is another dropdown in this project that works as it should. I copied the exact same code and attempted to use that as a template and it appears that it does not recognize the information from this dropdown, even though valid results are selectable options in the ddl.

Comment: he means, what happens when you use `ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedValue`? does it throw an exception? does it return a null value? An Empty string?

Comment: Throws empty string.

Comment: it throws an empty string? You mean it returns an empty string AND throws an exception? Or it just returns an empty string? Either way i'd inspect the page source and see if the "value" attribute is actually being populated

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want to use

```
 Me.ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedValue
```

Comment: This is what I used, and it is not capturing any data....        MyCommand.Parameters("@CONTACTTYPE").Value = Me.DropDownList1.SelectedValue
        MyCommand.Parameters("@FACASSIGN").Value = Me.ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedValue

Comment: See I have a dropdown that is already being used as a variable as well, but this one will not accept the same methodology. Thank you for helping me out on this one....

Comment: @Clark_Kent can't help you if the code you posted doesn't match what you actually have

Comment: That is verbatim what I have.

Comment: @Clark_Kent in the question you have SelectedItem.Text

Comment: I changed it based on what you recommended when you originally said to. However, it was still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
MyCommand.Parameters("@FACASSIGN").Value = 
    Me.ddlFacultyAssign.Items.Item(Me.ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedIndex).Text.Trim
```

And have you considered putting your dropdownlist and gridview in an update panel?

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, this server was hit in a ransomware attack, so we rebuilt in C#, it works as expected now.